# How can i write a function which takes number(n) as input and automatically creates  (n) number of objects for a class

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
    Node "obj"+i =new Node();
}

obj1.Node_val(2,3);
obj2.Node_val(9,8);
```

i tried this, but not works.

Please can you help. Thank you.

Comment: Using what language? Where will input be taken from? How?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an array, i.e., a `Node[]`:

```
public Node[] createNodes(int num) {

    Node[] nodes = new Node[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        nodes[i] = new Node();

    return nodes;
}
```

or a `List<Node>`:

```
public List<Node> createNodes(int num) {

    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>(num);

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        nodes.add(new Node());

    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: yes can be done, but what i want is, Node is the class created by me to represent nodes in WSN, and if i enter how many nodes i want, the function should create that number of Node objects. if i use this, and try to call

Comment: call one function of Node class like, obj[0].value() it is giving errorjava.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Then either `value()` throws an NPE or you haven't initialized `obj[0]` properly.

Comment: If you have some relationship between your nodes in the WSN, you can always do something like `obj[3].setNeighbours(obj[2], obj[9]);` but I suggest you do that once you've created all nodes (otherwise you can't be sure you've created the neighbours you want to reference).

Comment: thanks if i write like below it works.                             Node[] obj =new Node[n];
obj[0]= new Node();
obj[0].Node_val(2,3);

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Node> createNodes(List<IntPoint> coords)
{
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for (int i = 0; i < coords.size(); ++i)
    {
        nodes.add(new Node(coords.get(i).getX(), coords.get(i).getY());
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

Read between the lines and fill in the blanks with the `IntPoint` class.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this. you get a list of objects, which you can call on later at will. List lets you nicely add/ remove objects when you are done with them

```
List<SomeObject> objectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < totalObjectsNeeded; i++) {
    objectList.add(new SomeObject());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about Array / ArrayList ?

```
public List<Foo> getObjects(int noOfObjectsToBeCreated){
List<Foo> lst = new ArrayList<Foo>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < noOfObjectsToBeCreated ; i ++){
    lst.add(new Foo());//storing reference
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might want to use an array

```
Node [] nodes = new Node [num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; nodes [i++] = new Node () );
Node [0].Node_val (2, 3);
Node [1].Node_val (9, 8);
```